# Is there a way to combine/flatten multiple edges together that are in a checkerboard pattern?

Tags: mesh

I've looked everywhere on this and all i see are the typical instructions on how to merge edges together that are perpendicular to each other (such as two cylinders that need to be merged together on there ends using Bridge). But what i'm referring to is two flat planes in the shape of a triangle comprised of multiple edges (that criss-cross together in a checkerboard pattern) which i need to be laid on top of each other and merged (so that it auto-creates all the vertex points proving they've indeed been merged). Does anyone know what to do to accomplish this or is it not possible in Blender. Maybe a addon somewhere?? Anyway, see attachment. Oh and thanks!

Here's the screenshot
[image]

Comment: You need to post an image, rather than describe it.

Comment: What attachment?

Comment: I know, i tried, but the page kept giving me the wrong error saying i didn't have enough characters typed in, when all along it was because i attached a pic being a new member without enough credits. Don't know why the webmaster didn't simply code a script to say something like "new users with under 10 credits can't attach pics" or whatever.  Anyway, after trying 4 - 5 times i got flustered and just hit post without the pic. I wish i could have attached it. Now i can only hope someone knows the problem i'm facing without it. I read the new users rule page btw. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you post a picture on imgur.com and post the link here?

Comment: Take a look at this image: http://i.imgur.com/uVccdFA.png. Then click the word *edit* just below the text of your question, and include a screenshot.

Comment: I hope the mods don't mind my linking to a pic and providing the link in my post. I surely don't deserve 2 negative marks against me when it was the webmasters fault for not having the page trigger the correct - and 'common' i may add - new user error message. Then again, it's possible it could be Firefox's new (squirrely) version that caused the wrong error message, i don't know. Anyway, will edit post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should be able to select the 2 planes and **Join** so they are the one mesh. Then if you select the vertices you want merged you can click **Remove Doubles** and it will remove the duplicate vertices, essentially merging them together.

EDIT: Now that I understand what you were meaning, the only suggestion I have is to get rid of the vertical edges and create them within the original mesh. I tried it myself and it's a little tedious, but gets the same result I think you're after. First subdivide the bottom edge into how many segments you want, but remember that the Number of Cuts is one less than the number of segments (eg. 9 cuts for 10 segments) and then manually connect each set of vertices and pressing J. If that doesn't achieve the results you're after then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas :)

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, yet when going back into Edit mode the vertical lines (i.e. edges) still aren't melded together with the horizontal ones. Both the horizontal and vertical lines are of the same mesh, but i can't get them to 'flatten' so that.... you know! .....the little vertices are created. Here's another pic of just the vertical lines/edges selected, above the horizontal ones which are underneath. It's all one mesh. They were two meshes, so i used Ctrl + J to join them, yet after switching to Edit mode you'll notice no vertex points were created. Thanks btw! Pic link:

Comment: Wouldn't let me add the pic in the above message so here's a new comment with the pic link. Thanks for the help btw!!  Pic link: http://imgur.com/zi0xEG5

Comment: I've just updated my answer which hopefully helps. There's probably easier ways to do it, but I'm fairly new to Blender myself.

Comment: That's just it, i need an easier way, as i have about 100 of these to finish and didn't want to use J manually. It would be awesome if the BF devs or someone who knows python, to add in a script to meld large/numerous portions of mesh together. Oh well, time to wear out the J key :)  Hey much thanks for the help Danial. I really do appreciate it!